# How to Fix a Missing MySQL Socket (Mamp)?

Tags: mysql, sql, mamp, mysql.sock

```
Darshans-MacBook-Air-2:~ Darshan1$ sudo mkdir /var/mysql
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
```

What to type in password?

mysql.sock not showing in folder

Comment: try: **sudo su** and then enter password. then you get a root shell #

Answer (score 0):

try this to see where the socket is. MySQL will create on startup

```
MariaDB [yourSchema]> show variables like '%socket%';
+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name                           | Value           |
+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+
| performance_schema_max_socket_classes   | 10              |
| performance_schema_max_socket_instances | -1              |
| socket                                  | /tmp/mysql.sock |
+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.07 sec)

MariaDB [yourSchema]>
```

Comment: how to perform this sorry but i'm new to mysql and terminal @Bernd Buffen

Comment: first, check is the MySQL service is running. Can you connect to the database. Try : **ps -ax|grep mysqld** to see if MySQL is running and you can take a look in the file my.cnf . there you can see where the socket is created when the service is run